# Use jQuery with RequireJS separately

Tags: javascript, jquery, include, requirejs, require

I am trying to load and use jQuery, I do not want to use the RequireJs+jQuery bundle because I am not planning to use the latest version.
However it seems the document ready event it is not getting executed,

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: 'js/'
});


require([
    "jquery.min",
    "jquery.alpha",
    "jquery.beta"
], function($) {

    console.log('require js okay');

    define(['jquery'], function ($) {

        $(document).ready(function() {

            console.log('jquery has loaded');
            $('body').alpha().beta();

        });

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery [exports itself as a named module](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/861a45b8fffc2073baa9f62b0648f395f0695f3e/src/exports.js). This means you need to add a path to your config options to properly return jQuery as a module.

```
  paths: {
    "jquery": "js/jquery,
  },
```

Comment: calling `jquery.min` will still NOT return you jQuery object. The path **MUST** be literally `jquery` to return jQuery.

Comment: I still don't quite understand how this works. If jQuery exports itself as a named module, why do i have to configure it in the first place? Shouldn't it automatically detect jquery as a module? I have jQuery loaded through a CDN, i'm not entirely sure how you configure the path. Should i put the jquery cdn link in the path?